# adb is not responding in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

i am using android studio and it was working fine till yesterday. today when i tried to run the App. i received the error shown in the image below.

i looked for solution in this website and i did the following but nothing solved the issue:

1-killed the adb server manually. but when i tried to restart it manully,, it could not start.

2-uninstalled android studio and resinstalled it again.

3- i build the project using Build -> make project

and nothing of the above mentioned steps solved the problem.

please let me know how to solve it?[image]

Comment: Try this: Open Task Manager-->Processes-->adb.exe-->End Process and then restart Android studio on windows.

Comment: You can kill adb server from command promt also .C:\sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by:

1- ctrl + Alt+ del

2-go to process tab

3-look for "explorer.exe"

4-right click on it and choose "end process tree"

5-go to File->new task->write "explorer.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps sequentially...
**Step1:**

```
Tools > Android > (Uncheck) Enable ADB Integration
```

**Step 2:**

```
Tools > Android > (Check) Enable ADB Integration
```

Comment: Disable your firewall or antivirus  for a while and try again.

Comment: ok i will..but i want to know: after step1 should i close the studio and re open it and apply strp2?

Comment: by the way, adb is never among the processes in the task manager